Composer throws error "Could not find package codeigniter4\appstarter with stability stable"
I am a beginner in codeigniter, trying to create a project using the command line using composer create-project codeigniter4\appstarter project-folder but it showed this error:

Could not find package codeigniter4\appstarter with stability stable.

I tried restarting my computer and trying out different commands but I have no idea what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! Here is the picture of what happened


Composer package names are separated by / not \ so you want codeigniter4/appstarter rather than codeigniter4\appstarter

As an aside, when asking about error messages, always copy and paste the exact text you got if possible. In this case, you made two mistakes while retyping it, one adding the word "site" which doesn't appear in the screenshot, and more seriously switching the \ back to a / which hid the crucial clue.
